# STARTUPE2 in Vivado?

Tags: fpga, spi, xilinx, vivado

I am kinda new to FPGA , am trying to set up SPI connection to the Flash memory on my Artyx- 7 board ( Basy-3 ). Problem is pin C11 is a configuration dedicated pin which provides clock to the SPI as well.
Board documents says I need to use STARTUPE2 to instantiate access to that pin after config clocks are over.
Unfortunately I have no idea where to find and instantiate that STARTUPE2. Checked all IP catalogs as well as all online resources but no avail.

Comment: It's all over google. "STARTUPE2", including Xilinx guide

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `STARTUPE2` is not an IP.  It is a primitive.  That means you can use it like a module in your Verilog or VHDL code.  It is documented in Ch. 5 of [UG470](https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/user_guides/ug470_7Series_Config.pdf) and Ch. 5 of [UG953](https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx2021_1/ug953-vivado-7series-libraries.pdf).

Also see [https://ohm.bu.edu/~dean/Xilinx/KCPSM6_Release7_30Sept13/Reference_Designs/SPI/KC705_KCPSM6_SPI_Flash_reference_design.pdf](https://ohm.bu.edu/%7Edean/Xilinx/KCPSM6_Release7_30Sept13/Reference_Designs/SPI/KC705_KCPSM6_SPI_Flash_reference_design.pdf).

This example puts a clock on the CCLK pin.

```
module main(input clock_in);
   STARTUPE2 STARTUPE2
     (.CLK(1'b0),
      .GSR(1'b0),
      .GTS(1'b0),
      .KEYCLEARB(1'b1),
      .PACK(1'b0),
      .PREQ(),

      // Drive clock.
      .USRCCLKO(clock_in),
      .USRCCLKTS(1'b0),

      // These control the DONE pin.  UG470 says USRDONETS should
      // usually be low to enable DONE output.  But by default
      // (i.e. when the STARTUPE2 is not instaintiated), the DONE pin
      // goes to hi-z after initialization.  This is how to do that.
      .USRDONEO(1'b0),
      .USRDONETS(1'b1),

      .CFGCLK(),
      .CFGMCLK(),
      .EOS());
endmodule // main
```

Answer (score 1):

> where to find

Where ever you left it!  Or are you asking if you need to include a VHDL library (if you're using VHDL)?  In that case, you'll need

```
Library UNISIM;
use UNISIM.vcomponents.all;
```

What you should be asking is 'where to put' it.  You must make sure to instantiate it in the top level of your design.

STARTUPE2 is well-documented, I don't think you looked very hard.  See page 564 of the [7 series vivado documentation](https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx2018_2/ug953-vivado-7series-libraries.pdf).

Here is an example in VHDL, but there is an example in Verilog in the documentation if that's what you're using:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

library UNISIM;
use UNISIM.VComponents.all;


entity startup_block is
  Port ( bit_wiggler : out std_logic);
end startup_block;

architecture Behavioral of startup_block is
  signal spi_clk : std_logic := '0';
begin

STARTUPE2_inst : STARTUPE2
generic map (
 PROG_USR => "FALSE", -- Activate program event security feature. Requires encrypted bitstreams.
 SIM_CCLK_FREQ => 0.0 -- Set the Configuration Clock Frequency(ns) for simulation.
)
port map (
 CFGCLK => open,      -- 1-bit output: Configuration main clock output
 CFGMCLK => open,     -- 1-bit output: Configuration internal oscillator clock output
 EOS => open,         -- 1-bit output: Active high output signal indicating the End Of Startup.
 PREQ => open,        -- 1-bit output: PROGRAM request to fabric output
 CLK => '0',          -- 1-bit input: User start-up clock input
 GSR => '0',          -- 1-bit input: Global Set/Reset input (GSR cannot be used for the port name)
 GTS => '0',          -- 1-bit input: Global 3-state input (GTS cannot be used for the port name)
 KEYCLEARB => '1',    -- 1-bit input: Clear AES Decrypter Key input from Battery-Backed RAM (BBRAM)
 PACK => '0',         -- 1-bit input: PROGRAM acknowledge input
 USRCCLKO => spi_clk, -- 1-bit input: User CCLK input
 USRCCLKTS => '0',    -- 1-bit input: User CCLK 3-state enable input
 USRDONEO => '1',     -- 1-bit input: User DONE pin output control
 USRDONETS => '0'     -- 1-bit input: User DONE 3-state enable output
);
-- End of STARTUPE2_inst instantiation

-- do stuff 

end Behavioral;
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  I use Verilog in Vivado.  My question is where to set up the module ?      Cannot find it in the IP Catalog.   Is it somewhere else in the tools ?  Sorry I know it is too much of “newbie-ness “